# <input autocomplete="off" this is not working i am using in angular 13. still is showing lastPass.. in my input filed

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, angular13, lastpass

this lastpass... is still showing need to remove this from input field

I have used for this "autocomplete"="off", aria-autocomplete="none"

but still not solved my problem for remove this lastPass.. what i can do.

can anyone send me solution for this.

so i can resolve my issue..
[image]

Comment: According to https://support.lastpass.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=lastpass&topicId=LastPass%2Fc_lp_prevent_fields_from_being_filled_automatically.html&_LANG=enus, the user has to explicitly set their lastpass extension to _respect_ `autocomplete="off"`, otherwise it will simply ignore this.